# Prove that if $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation with dim[$W$] = $n$ = dim[Rng($T$)], then $T$ is onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Prove that if $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation with dim[$W$] = $n$ = dim[Rng($T$)], then $T$ is onto.

I know that a linear transformation is onto if and only if Rng($T$) = $W$. So it seems simple enough that if dim[$W$] = $n$ and dim[Rng($T$)] = $n$ then dim[$W$] = dim[Rng($T$)]. But I'm not sure where to go from here. Would it be as simple as $W$ = Rng($T$) from the previous step or is there more to it?

Comment: @JohnHughes There’s no need for $V$ to be finite-dimensional, and $W$ is given as being finite-dimensional. You were probably misled by the OP’s typo of $V\to V$ for $V\to W$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $\operatorname{Rng}(T)\subseteq W$, but the only $n$-dimensional subspace of $W$ is itself, so equality holds.

Comment: yes I did mean that, updated to reflect that.